# Complex differentiation, Cauchy Riemann

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

By using the definition of complex differentiation and the complex derivative, how can we show that $f'(z_0)= \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_0)-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z_0)). $
I know this is a standard result but want to know how to derive it myself. I know that if $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ then $\frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_0)+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z_0))=0 $ but can't seem to see where the result of $f'$ comes from?

Also why do we have $f'(z_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_0)$?

Comment: Can you show that $f'=\partial_x f$?

Comment: Is this result just a consequence of taking the directional derivative in the x direction? And since the limit must exist for all paths to $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$, then $f'=\partial _x f $? Is this correct? I can show this yes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Now can you find a similar equation involving $\partial_yf$?